# Work out a solution for codality?

Tags: c++, algorithm

A zero-indexed array A consisting of N different integers is given. The array contains integers in the range `[1..(N + 1)]`, which means that exactly one element is missing.

Your goal is to find that missing element.

Write a function:

```
int solution(int A[], int N);
```

that, given a zero-indexed array `A`, returns the value of the missing element.

For example, given array A such that:

```
A[0] = 2 A[1] = 3 A[2] = 1 A[3] = 5
```

the function should return `4`, as it is the missing element.

Assume that:

```
N is an integer within the range [0..100,000];
the elements of A are all distinct;
each element of array A is an integer within the range [1..(N + 1)].
```

Complexity:

```
expected worst-case time complexity is O(N);
expected worst-case space complexity is O(1), beyond input storage (not counting the storage required for input arguments).
```

It doesn't work for a case that there are two elements

```
int solution(vector<int> &A) {

    sort(A.begin(), A.end());
    int missingIndex = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++)
    {
        if ( i != A[i]-1)
        {
            missingIndex = i+1;
        }

    }
    return missingIndex;
}
```

Comment: Using sort will result in not having the required worst-cased time complexity of O(N). You'll have to do something smarter than that. Like starting at element 1 (A[0]), get its value (2), going to element 2 (A[1]), mark that as 'seen' (e.g. by giving it value 0), do the same for A[1]. Done all of them, scan the array and find the one that's not marked as seen. That should be O(n) in time, and  O(1) in space, at the expense of screwing up the original data. Nice puzzle, but I just don't feel like writing the code right now.

Comment: @ecotax In this case, sorting can achieve a `O(N)` complexity. As you have got a limited range of values, it is suitable for a counting-sort. What is really limiting is the `O(1)` space limit :)

Comment: @fjardon indeed, in this case you could use an efficient enough sort algorithm. Also, Raistmaj found an even simpler/smarter solution. Nice one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your array is zero-indexed and the numbers are from 1 to N+1, the statement should be:

```
if ( i != A[i]-1)
```

**Also, you should immediately break out from the for loop after updating the missingIndex because all entries beyond the missing element shall have (i != A[i]-1)**

Moreover because of sorting your solution is O(NlogN) and not O(N).

Instead you can sum all the elements in the array `(using unsigned long long int)` and check its difference from `N(N+1)/2`

Comment: still didn't pass the test cases, for single element, and two elements that are in the array

Comment: Checking its difference from N(N+1)/2 is brilliant !

Comment: still this wrong, if ( i != A[i]-1)
  {
   missingIndex = i+1;
   break;
  }

Comment: int solution(vector<int> &A) {
 sort(A.begin(), A.end());
 int missingIndex = 0;

 for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++)
 {
  if ( i != A[i]-1)
  {
   missingIndex = i+1;
   break;
  }

 }
 return missingIndex;
}

Comment: The sum of the elements is the right answer, don't sort or anything, just compute the sum and and substract it with the actual value, is O(n) and O(1). I did this test some years ago. IMHO Codality, in order to test programmer skills, is one of the worst things a company can do, still a lot of "big" companies use it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the simple math formula for an [arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression) to get the sum of all numbers from 1 to N+1.  Then iterate over all the given numbers and calculate that sum.  The missing element will be the difference between the two sums.

```
int solution(std::vector<int> &a) {
    uint64_t sum = (a.size() +1 ) * (a.size() + 2) / 2;
    uint64_t actual = 0;
    for(int element : a) {
        actual += element;
    }
    return static_cast<int>(sum - actual);
}
```

Comment: can I get your contact am immigrant living in Austria too :) ?

Answer (score 1):

Use all the power of STL:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

int solution(vector<int> &A) {
    return std::accumulate(A.begin(), A.end(), (A.size()+1) * (A.size()+2) / 2, std::minus<int>());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses the sign of the values as a flag. It needs at worst two pass over the elements. The N(N+1)/2 solution needs exactly one pass.

```
int solution(vector<int> &a) {
    int n = (int)a.size();
    for(auto k : a)
    {
        int i = abs(k) - 1;
        if (i != n)
            a[i] = -a[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        if (a[i]>0)
            return i+1;
    return n+1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way and thought of posting it here for my own reference for future and for others :)

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <numeric>
int solution(vector<int> &A) {
   uint64_t sumAll = (A.size() + 1) * (A.size() + 2) / 2;
   uint64_t sumA = std::accumulate(A.begin(), A.end(), 0);
   return sumAll- sumA;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve it with this solution maybe there is something better but I test it with different values and find it work fine while the other solutions gives me strange results.
as example:

```
std::vector<int> A = { 12,13,11,14,16 };
std::vector<int> A2 = { 112,113,111,114,116 };


int  Solution(std::vector<int> &A)
{
int temp;
for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); ++i)
{
    for (int j = i+1;j< A.size();++j )  
{
    if (A[i] > A[j])
        {
            temp = A[i];
            A[i] = A[j];
            A[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < A.size()-1;++i)
{
    if ((A[i] + 1 != A[i + 1]))
    {
    return (A[i] + 1);
    }
    if(i+1 == A.size() - 1)
    return (A[i+1] + 1);

}}
```

Now Everything fine but if I use the array above with the methods below, I will get wrong values excepts with small numbers <10;

```
 std::vector<int> A = { 12,13,11,14,16 };
 int Solution_2(std::vector<int> &A) 
{
unsigned int n = A.size() + 1;
long long int estimated = n * (n + 1) / 2;
long long int total = 0;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) total += A[i];
return estimated - total;
}
```

I will get this result -45.

or this one also the same result if I use array A  :

```
std::vector<int> A = { 12,13,11,14,16 };
int Solution_3(std::vector<int> &A) 
{
 uint64_t sumAll = (A.size() + 1) * (A.size() + 2) / 2;
 uint64_t sumA = std::accumulate(A.begin(), A.end(), 0);
 return sumAll - sumA;
}
```

Hope Someone explains why this happens.